What event we must use for confirmation template by email?
I use the email receipt, I would like to modify the sending email. If we modify the template it does not work.

I tried several events, but none executed. Can you confirm for me which event is use when sending the confirmation template by email ?
I Try
protected void SMEmail_RowInserted(PXCache cache, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e)
{      
  var row = (SMEmail)e.Row;
  if (row==null) return;
  string objetemail=row.Subject;
  EMailAccount compteemail=PXSelect<EMailAccount,Where<EMailAccount.emailAccountID, Equal<Required<EMailAccount.emailAccountID>>>>.Select(this.Base,row.MailAccountID);
  EMailAccount compteemail_noreply=PXSelect<EMailAccount,Where<EMailAccount.address, Equal<Required<EMailAccount.address>>>>.Select(this.Base,"noreply@gmail.com");
  if (compteemail==null) return;
  if (compteemail_noreply==null) return;
  if ((objetemail.Contains("[Accusé de réception]")==true) && ((row.IsIncome==false) || (row.IsIncome==null)) && compteemail.Address=="supportflex@gmail.com")
    {
      row.MailAccountID=compteemail_noreply.EmailAccountID;
    }      
}   

or with this event
protected void CRSMEmail_RowInserted(PXCache cache, PXRowInsertedEventArgs e)
{
  
  var row = (CRSMEmail)e.Row;
  if (row==null) return;
  string objetemail=row.Subject;
  EMailAccount compteemail=PXSelect<EMailAccount,Where<EMailAccount.emailAccountID, Equal<Required<EMailAccount.emailAccountID>>>>.Select(this.Base,row.MailAccountID);
  EMailAccount compteemail_noreply=PXSelect<EMailAccount,Where<EMailAccount.address, Equal<Required<EMailAccount.address>>>>.Select(this.Base,"noreply@gmail.com");
  if (compteemail==null) return;
  if (compteemail_noreply==null) return;
  if ((objetemail.Contains("[Accusé de réception]")==true) && ((row.IsIncome==false) || (row.IsIncome==null)) && compteemail.Address=="support@flexforyou.fr")
    {
      row.MailAccountID=compteemail_noreply.EmailAccountID;
    }
}


LAREM What is your question here? Do you want to capture the event when 'Confirmation template' is modified?
